# OS error in command prompt when trying to run both versions of apache

Tags: php, apache, dll, cmd, operating-system

I am following this tutorial in order to setup mySQL and php in my computer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZ2zbO6PABk‎&feature=youtube_gdata_player

I am running a 64 bit windows 8

When I am downloading the 32 bit version that I downloaded from here:http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

and I am putting in the "apache24\bin" directory the msvce110.dll that I downloaded from here:(all with the tutorial)http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr110 (the zip version)

When I ran the httpd file in the "apache24\bin" from the command prompt I got an error message "The application was not able to start correctly (0xc000007b)" I googled it and figured out it happens because i'm trying to rum 32 bit apache on a 64 bit system. that was the dead end for my first try. (32 bit)

---

Now, I did just the same with the 64 bit version of apache.

At first when I started running the apache  it worked fine and when I typed in my browser "localhost" I saw the wanted message from apache. I could start it, stop it... anything I need.
The tutorial shows that in order to synchronise apache and php I hould add to the "conf\httpd.txt" after the "#loadmodule"s the following lines:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I double checked that the location "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll" exists. now I encuntered a different problem: I couldn't start my apache any more. everytime I tried I got the following error:
"the requested operation has failed"

when I tried to run the "apache24bin\httpd" I got another error (this time written in the console an not as a popup message)

```
    "httpd: Syntax error on line 73 of ... cannot load modules/mod_
    access_compact.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application/"
```

I am stuck. no matter what I'm trying to run, it has problems with my operating system. how can I resolve at least one of the problems above?

Comment: Can somebody tell me why is nobody even looking at my question?? I did a lot of research myself before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't understand why you downloaded 32 bit version apache. there is 64 bit version on the page. running 32 bit version apache on 64 bit os may couse problems like this.

2) I recommend you to use wamp or xammp. these softwares will install all everything for you...

Comment: I installed the 32 bit because that is what's suggested in the tutorial even for 64 bit oS. I'm trying to get recognized with those programs and I read the best way to do it is to unstall them seperately.

Comment: there must be differences between 32 bit and 64 bit installations, because download page provide them separately. if you use windows, the best way is using wamp etc. if you want to learn apache, the best way is using linux with apache, php (LAMP). Recognizing apache on windows is not good practice, I think.

Comment: According to what I read (and to what I saw in the tutorial) it's impossible to download 64 bit software on a 32 bit OS but possible to download both on a 64 bit version (although the 64 bit would be faster)

Comment: They do not say that we can install 32 bit apache installation file  on 64 os "on download page". All 32 bit softwares may not installable on 64 os. This is not general rule for all softwares. plus. please check your error messages; they are pointing your OS. Your problem is definetely about you try 32 bit apache on 64 bit os. after all, you may choose hard way and try to solve installing 32 bit s.ware on 64 bit os. (or just change installation file). its your choice

Comment: as you saw in my question I had problem when I tried to install the 64 bit version too.